# Assert that page contents are correct with no extra elements in it

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am writing automation code and I was asked to make test case to assert that page contents are correct and if there is any extra element (text) in the page the test should fail I have no idea how to make the test fail if there is extra element in the page any suggestions to help me?

Comment: What do you means by _extra elements_, is that extra HTML tag or text, what?

Comment: Duplicate label (text) for example username label displayed twice at the page

Comment: You should use Visual comparison for this using something like applitools. Comparing HTML or elements will make tests more brittle and wont allow developers to freely update code in HTML, which is always needed for applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
    driver.getPageSource().contains("Text which you looking for");
```

You can use above in an assert statement and verify. Test passes if the text(label) is found else fails.